# I want to refresh UITableView in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I am using UITabBarController and I am setting some controllers in it ,when i tab to different controllers it works fine,But If iam inserting data in database and tab to second controller ,it dnt show the data except restarting the application.I think tabbar loads all controllers ,so i want to refresh my TableView so that I can view added data 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ali try reloading data in the tableView.....try this `[self.tableView reloadData];` when you come back to your view where u want to display the data in the tableView i.e the view which contain `UITableView`

Hope this may help u!